# why does the chazzan stand for the entire davening?

Tags: tefilla, chazzan-prayer-leader, standing-sitting

From what I have seen, other than tachanun (nefilat apayim) the chazzan stands for the entire davening. Why is this so? Why not sit for things like krias shema?

Comment: My guess is practical -- between needing a place to put that chair and needing to be visible/audible to the kehal enough for people to know where he is, it's probably easier to just stand.  Assuming he does sit down for leining, it's not *that* long to just stand for most services.

Comment: See perhaps Megillah 21a

Comment: @DoubleAA isn't that said regarding teaching/learning torah, not tefilla?

Comment: They don't call it an "Amud" for nothing.

Comment: Kabvod hazibur would be my guess. BTW I have seen Chazzonim with health issues sit during parts of the Chazzoras Hashatz on Yomim Noraim.

Comment: Are we specifically talking about Ashkenazim?

Comment: @WAF I don't see any such indication.

Answer (score 3):

He is the the *Shliach*  - the emissary - to the King, so to speak, and a emissary always stands before a king.

Comment: Interesting... A source would improve the quality of this answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is addressed by the gemarah Yerushalmi Sotah 7:4 which learns the idea out of the pasuk in Devarim 27:26

> אָרוּר, אֲשֶׁר לֹא-יָקִים אֶת-דִּבְרֵי הַתּוֹרָה-הַזֹּאת

The gemarah explains that the standing (up) of the torah implies that the Chazzan should stand.

> ארור אשר לא יקים את דברי התורה הזאת. וכי יש תורה נופלת. שמעון בן יקים אומר זה החזן שהוא עומד.

---

CF Ramban ad loc who seems to apply this only to the lifting of the torah (hagbah) but I believe the plain reading of the gemarah supports my answer.